# Contour plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

In the following lines I am calculating the quantity "chisquare" as a function of two variables, a and s :

```
def getChi(Pa, Ps_theory, Fab_matrix):
    chisquare = linalg.transpose(Pa-Ps_theory).dot(Fab_matrix).dot(Pa-Ps_theory)
    return chisquare

n = 64
sigma = 3.
key = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
sigma_hat = (float(n)/(2.*np.pi*sigma))
A_list = np.arange(0.1, 0.7, 0.01)

for a in A_list:
    for s in np.arange(sigma_hat-3.5, sigma_hat+3.5, 0.01):
        Ps_theory = a*np.exp(-(key*key/(2.*s*s)))
        chi_square[a,s] = getChi(Pa, Ps_theory, Fab_matrix)
```

Now I need to plot the contour plots of chisquare, after subtracting its minimum. I tried to do that in the following way:

```
fig = plt.figure()
        ax = figura.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_title('Contour_plots_Chi_square{}'.format(n))
        ax.set_xlabel('A')
        ax.set_ylabel('sigma')
        plt.contour(A_list, np.arange(sigma_hat-3.5, sigma_hat+3.5, 0.01), chi_square)
        plt.savefig('chi_square_contour_plot/Chi_square_contour_plot{}.svg'.format(n))
```

But it does not work, because it seems that:

```
plt.contour(A_list, np.arange(sigma_hat-3.5, sigma_hat+3.5, 0.01), chi_square)
```

does not follow the correct syntax. Could someone explain what is the correct syntax?

Comment: That line seems good to me. However you have a missing colon (:) in the inner for-loop. Can't see it for myself without the values of Pa and Fab_matrix

Comment: @AdityaJoshi I have edited the post so as to include the (:) in the loop, thanks. As regards Pa and Fab_matrix, they are quite complicated arrays and matrices, so I decided not to include them in the post, but you can really replace them with any array or matrix you like, I don't think that's the issue. Probably it is more about the syntax

Comment: Could you please post the error that you get? Regarding syntax the line is fine.

Comment: The `x` and `y` arguments of `countour` need to be 2D arrays. You only provide 1D arrays (or lists, I'm not sure). Given the 1D arrays you can create the 2D versions with `numpy.meshgrid`.

Comment: @hitzg thanks it actually seems to work with numpy.meshgrid